# Timer triggered GPDMA transfer to SRAM

Tags: c, lpc, nxp-microcontroller

I want to transfer data from an external AD-Converter. I get parallel 11 bits which I store in an array. I wanna set up a timer triggered GPDMA transfer, that every 50ns fires a DMA stream and transfer data. After the transfer is complete, the RAM address should be incremented.

The MCU, I work with is the LPC4088 Quickstart Board.
The CPU and Peripheral Clock, runs with 120Mhz

I studied the UM of LPC4088 and already wrote some simple basic code.

```
#include "LPC407x_8x_177x_8x.h"

#define PERIPHSRAM1           0x20004000

char adcData[11] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};

volatile uint32_t DMATCCOUNT = 0;
volatile uint32_t DMAERRCOUNT = 0;


int main(){

    uint8_t size = sizeof(adcData);

    LPC_SC->PCONP |= (1 << 22);                     //Power & Clock  Timer2

    LPC_TIM2->CTCR = (0 << 0);                      //Timer Mode
    LPC_TIM2->PR = 0;
    LPC_TIM2->TCR = (1 << 1);                       //Reset timer

    LPC_TIM2->TC = 0;               
    LPC_TIM2->MR0 = 5;                        //Match register to get 10MHz
    LPC_TIM2->MCR = (1 << 1)                        //Reset Timer
                    |(1 << 0);                   //Interrupt if MR0 matches
    LPC_TIM2->EMR = 0x31;                 //toggle pin to check wave output
    LPC_TIM2->TCR = (1 << 1);                       //reset timer again

    LPC_SC->PCONP |= (1 << 29);                     //Power & Clock DMA
    LPC_GPDMACH0->CConfig = 0;                      //disable CH0
    LPC_GPDMA->Config |= (1 << 0);                  //enable DMA Controller
    LPC_SC->DMAREQSEL = 0x010;                 //Set T2 MAT0 as DMA request

    LPC_GPDMA->IntErrClr |= 0x0FF;
    LPC_GPDMA->IntTCClear |= 0x0FF;

    LPC_GPDMACH0->CDestAddr = PERIPHSRAM1;
    LPC_GPDMACH0->CSrcAddr = (uint32_t) &adcData;
    LPC_GPDMACH0->CControl = size
                            |(0x00 << 12) //Source Burst size: 1
                            |(0x00 << 15) //Destination Burst size: 1 
                            |(0x02 << 18) //Source width:     32 bit
                            |(0x02 << 21) //Destination width:32 bit
                            |(0x01 << 26) //Source increment: enabled
                            |(0x01 << 27) //Destination increment: enabled
                            |(0x01 << 31); //TermCount interrupt enabled

    LPC_GPDMACH0->CControl |= (4 << 1)      //Source peripheral: Timer2 MR0
                           |(0 << 11);      //Memory to memory trasnfer

    NVIC_SetVector(DMA_IRQn, (uint32_t) DMA_IRQHandler);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA_IRQn);

    LPC_GPDMACH0->CConfig |= 1;         //Enable channel
    LPC_TIM2->IR |= 0x0FF;              //CLear all timer interrupts
    LPC_TIM2->TCR = 0x01;               //start Timer

    while(!DMATCCOUNT);                 //Wait till transfer Complete

    while(1){

    }
}

void DMA_IRQHandler(void){
    uint32_t temp;
    DMATCCOUNT++;
    temp = LPC_GPDMA->IntTCStat;
    if(temp){
        DMATCCOUNT++;
        LPC_GPDMA->IntTCClear |= temp;
    }
    temp = LPC_GPDMA->IntErrStat;
    if(temp){
        DMAERRCOUNT++;
        LPC_GPDMA->IntErrClr |= temp;
    }
    return;
}


I expected data on address 0x20004000, but there is nothing. 

Hope any of you guys could help me.
```

Comment: It looks like are attempting DMA from RAM to RAM?

Comment: Exactly from flash to RAM

Comment: CSrcAddr sounds like source address, which you set to RAM. Then you set CDestAddr to address 0x20004000. If the destination is flash, well no wonder... Unless there's something very fancy going on with this MCU, you can't program flash memory through DMA.

Comment: But the UM mentioned a memory to memory transfer which I thought can transfer Data from flash to RAM, please stop me if I got it wrong.

Comment: I don't know this hardware, but it does look like you are attempting to DMA data from RAM to flash, not the other way around.

Comment: Alright thanks, I will overthink my code.